# What's the easiest way to get an OutOfMemoryException in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, out-of-memory

Just curious as to how I can get this error the easiest way.

Once I was trying to create a file navigator and I was creating Image thumbnails; that turned out awful.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

```
void Foo()
{
   throw new OutOfMemoryException();
}
```

:)))

Comment: obvious answer is obvioius.

Comment: Why not throw it directly from `static void Main()`? Creating a whole new method is way too difficult and time consuming :)

Answer (score 5):

Create a very, very large string. Probably:

```
string s = new string('a', int.MaxValue);
```

will be enough.

If not, you can concat it to build even bigger string.

```
string ss = string.Concat(s, s);
```

Answer (score 4):

This does throw an `OutOfMemoryException`:

```
string s = " ";
while (true) s += s;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
for(var s=" ";;s+=s);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var x = new long[Int32.MaxValue];
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
new int[(ulong)-1];
```